# Turn text inside brackets to an array PHP

Tags: php, regex

If I have a string that looks like this:

```
$myString = "[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text";
```

I want it to be turned into:

```
$string = "This is a long text";
$arrayDigits[0] = 993;
$arrayDigits[1] = 112;
$arrayText[0] = "sometext";
$arrayText[1] = "moretext";
```

How can I do this with PHP?

I understand Regular Expressions is the solution. Please notice that `$myString` was just an example. There can be several brackets, not just two of each, as in my example.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: regexp is less likely to be the solution than exploding, looping, and a bit of if testing.... why not use sensible assignment of the values in the first place? rather than force this crazy formatting into your code?

Comment: @MarkBaker It's basically like on Stack Overflow where you can search "[php] search words", which will only match questions tagged with php.

Comment: Can you guarantee that $myString will always contain the same basic content, and in the same order? i.e. array texts first, then array digits and a single unenclosed string at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of:

```
<?php

function parseString($string) {
    // identify data in brackets
    static $pattern = '#(?:\[)([^\[\]]+)(?:\])#';
    // result container
    $t = array(
        'string' => null,
        'digits' => array(),
        'text' => array(),
    );

    $t['string'] = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use(&$t) {
        // shove matched string into digits/text groups
        $t[is_numeric($m[1]) ? 'digits' : 'text'][] = $m[1];
        // remove the brackets from the text
        return '';
    }, $string);

    return $t;
}

$string = "[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text";
$result = parseString($string);
var_dump($result);

/*
    $result === array(
        "string" => "This is a long text",
        "digits" => array(
            993,
            112,
        ),
        "text" => array(
            "sometext",
            "moretext",
        ),
    );
*/
```

(PHP5.3 - using closures)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$s = '[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text';
preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]/', $s, $m);
```

`$m[1]` will contain all texts in the brakets, after this you could check type of each value. Also, you could check this using two `preg_match_all`: at first time with pattern `/\[(\d+)\]/` (will return array of digits), in the second - pattern `/\[([a-zA-z]+)\]/` (that will return words):

```
$s = '[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text';
preg_match_all('/\[(\d+)\]/', $s, $matches);
$arrayOfDigits = $matches[1];
preg_match_all('/\[([a-zA-Z]+)\]/', $s, $matches);
$arrayOfWords = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with.

```
<?php

#For better display
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

#The String
$myString = "[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text";

#Initialize the array
$matches = array();

#Fill it with matches. It would populate $matches[1].
preg_match_all("|\[(.+?)\]|", $myString, $matches);

#Remove anything inside of square brackets, and assign to $string.
$string = preg_replace("|\[.+\]|", "", $myString);

#Display the results.
print_r($matches[1]);
print_r($string);
```

After that, you can iterate over the `$matches` array and check each value to assign it to a new array.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like yours you can make use of *named subpatterns* so to "tokenize" your string. With some little code, this can be made easily configurable with an array of tokens:

```
$subject = "[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text";

$groups = array(
    'digit' => '\[\d+]',
    'text' => '\[\w+]',
    'free' => '.+'
);
```

Each group contains the subpattern and it's name. They match in their order, so if the group *digit* matches, it won't give *text*  a chance (which is necessary here because `\d+` is a subset of `\w+`). This array can then turned into a full pattern:

```
foreach($groups as $name => &$subpattern)
    $subpattern = sprintf('(?<%s>%s)', $name, $subpattern);
unset($subpattern);

$pattern = sprintf('/(?:%s)/', implode('|', $groups));
```

The pattern looks like this:

```
/(?:(?<digit>\[\d+])|(?<text>\[\w+])|(?<free>.+))/
```

Everything left to do is to execute it against your string, capture the matches and filter them for some normalized output:

```
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches))
{
    $matches = array_intersect_key($matches, $groups);
    $matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
    $matches = array_map('array_values', $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

The matches are now nicely accessible in an array:

```
Array
(
    [digit] => Array
        (
            [0] => [993]
            [1] => [112]
        )

    [text] => Array
        (
            [0] => [sometext]
            [1] => [moretext]
        )

    [free] => Array
        (
            [0] => This is a long text
        )

)
```

The full example at once:

```
$subject = "[sometext][moretext][993][112]This is a long text";

$groups = array(
    'digit' => '\[\d+]',
    'text' => '\[\w+]',
    'free' => '.+'
);

foreach($groups as $name => &$subpattern)
    $subpattern = sprintf('(?<%s>%s)', $name, $subpattern);
unset($subpattern);

$pattern = sprintf('/(?:%s)/', implode('|', $groups));

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches))
{
    $matches = array_intersect_key($matches, $groups);
    $matches = array_map('array_filter', $matches);
    $matches = array_map('array_values', $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```